# Dividing shapefile into multiple shapefiles using an attribute value in QGIS Graphical Modeler

Tags: shapefile, qgis-2, qgis-modeler, batch, split-by-attribute

I have a shapefile with a column that have project references, I want to create a different shapefile for every project reference there is.

Note that the project references are not unique in the sense that there are multiple lines with the same reference.

Input example:

| ID | ref | clmnC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | abcd |
| 2 | 002 | addd |
| 3 | 001 | dsdd |
| 4 | 003 | sdsd |
| 5 | 003 | rzer |
| 6 | 002 | qdqd |
| 7 | 001 | ssqz |

Output wanted (3 tables in this example):

```
  ref clmnC          ref clmnC           ref clmnC
  001 abcd           002 addd            003 sdsd
  001 dsdd           002 qdqd            003 rzer
  001 ssqz
```

I tried listing unique values but that only return a table with only unique project references values, any solution to solve this problem using the graphical modeler in QGIS 2.18?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, using the ['Split Vector Layer'](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#split-vector-layer) tool, I was able to split my datasets based on the attribute I wanted.

[image: split_in_GM]

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative using PyQGIS where Graphical Modeler is not required.

Let's assume there is a point layer `'points'` with its corresponding attribute table accordingly, see image below.

[image: input]

*Task:* Split layer into several layers by `"value"` attribute and delete `"id"` field for each of it.

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor > New Editor` and paste the script below

```py
# imports
import os, sys

class SplitLayerToMany:
    # initiating layer's and field's names provided from user
    def __init__(self, layer_name, field_name):
        self.layer_name = layer_name
        self.field_name = field_name
    
    # setting up the input layer and defining required parameters
    def split_layer(self):
        # loading layer
        layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(self.layer_name)[0]
        layer_fields = layer.fields()
        idx_of_that_field = layer_fields.indexFromName(self.field_name)
        
        if not layer.isValid():
            raise ValueError("Layer failed to load!")
            sys.exit()
        
        # getting a set with unique key attributes
        list_attributes = []
        for feat in layer.getFeatures():
            list_attributes.append(feat.attributes()[idx_of_that_field])
        list_attributes = set(list_attributes)
        
        # checking a number of features in the input layer
        if layer.featureCount() < 2:
            raise ValueError("Layer contains only one feature. No reason to double save it")
        
        else:
            # getting a working dir, where the input layer is stored
            path_to_file = layer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri()
            working_dir = os.path.split(path_to_file)[0]
            
            # looping over attributes from the set, selecting features and saving them as a new single layer
            for i in list_attributes:
                selection = layer.selectByExpression('{0}=\'{1}\''.format(self.field_name, i))
                writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, working_dir + "/{}.shp".format(i), "UTF-8", layer.crs(), driverName = "ESRI Shapefile", onlySelected = True)
        
        layer.removeSelection()
        
my_class = SplitLayerToMany('points', 'value')
my_class.split_layer()
```

Press `Run script` [image: run script] and get the output

[image: output_folder]

[image: output_qgis]

---

**References:**

- [PyQGIS: Shapefile from Selected Features](https://opensourceoptions.com/blog/pyqgis-shapefile-from-selected-features/)
- [Exporting selected features to shapefile PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298430/exporting-selected-features-to-shapefile-pyqgis)
- [QGIS Export Shapefile using PyQgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153309/qgis-export-shapefile-using-pyqgis)
- [Getting path of project, or layer file in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34560/getting-path-of-project-or-layer-file-in-pyqgis)
- [“Select by Attribute” in QGIS using python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32521/select-by-attribute-in-qgis-using-python)
- [How to delete column/field in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109078/how-to-delete-column-field-in-pyqgis)