# QGIS: Splitting layer into individual shapefiles with the attribute as the shapefile name

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, splitting

In QGIS 3.14 I have created a layer containing multiple polygons from x/y coordinate data, but I now need to split those ploygons into individual layers/shapefiles by their different attributes - However, I need these new layers/ shapefiles to be named after the different attributes that they are split, but I only seem to be able to get layers numbered arbitarily 1 to x

Eg:
Attrbiute Field 4 has different feature numbers - eg. F021, F032, F063, which represent the individual polygons that I need seperated into different layers.
When I split by attribute to create the shapefiles I get field_4_1, field_4_2 etc. (where the _1 and _2 are arbitary numbers and not realated to the feature), instead of field_4_F021, field_4_F032 - or ideally just F021, F032 etc.

Comment: Check this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357776/dividing-shapefile-into-multiple-shapefiles-using-an-attribute-value-in-qgis-gra

Comment: In the Code I provided pay attention to `.format(I)`, there you will need to set a name you need

Comment: The `split vector layer` tool seems to be bugged in 3.14, it works as intended in 3.10.